# In Golang, what does it mean when an interface is used inside of a struct?

Tags: go, interface

New to Go here. I ran across some code that has the following related to DynamoDB:

```
type Dynamo interface {
    DescribeTableWithContext(
        aws.Context,
        *dynamodb.DescribeTableInput,
        ...request.Option,
    ) (*dynamodb.DescribeTableOutput, error)
}

type my_struct struct {
    Dynamo
}
```

Am I correct in assuming `my_struct` "implements" the Dynamo interface, and now can use the `DescribeTableWithContext` method?

Comment: It's more like it *only* satisfies the interface, however trying to invoke the method on a my_struct instance, without a real, concrete implementation will fail *at runtime*.

Comment: It means the same as if a non-interface type is inside: It is embedding and works like normal embedding i.e. you have a unnamed field of that type and as with pointer or map types you have to initialize it  before it becomes usable.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I correct in assuming my_struct "implements" the Dynamo interface

Not exactly. Whatever struct you initialize `my_struct` with for the `Dynamo` embed will be the thing that *implements* the interface. `my_struct` will however *satisfy* the `Dynamo` interface at compile time. As @mkopriva points out though, at runtime, this does require a concrete implementation of the embedded interface. So if you were to do something like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Adder interface {
    func Add(a, b int) int
}

type Embed struct {
    Adder
}

func PrintAdd(a Adder, first, second int) {
    fmt.Println(a.Add(first, second))
}

func main() {
    e := Embed{}
    PrintAdd(e, 1, 2)
}
```

This code would compile but at runtime, the call to `PrintAdd` will fail since the embedded interface implementation has not been set.

If you replace the above main with:

```
type adder struct {}

func (a adder) Add(first, second int) int {
     return first + second
}

func main() {
    e := Embed{adder{}}
    PrintAdd(e, 1, 2)
}
```

Things will work as expected.

> ...and now can use the DescribeTableWithContext method?

Yes, assuming that you have provided an interface implementation during initialization.

EDIT: Added an explanation for what it means to implement an interface versus just satisfy it.

Comment: Your opening statement is false. Embedding an interface type into a struct definition does *not* mean that the struct implements the interface. For callers, it will appear that it does, but calls of (in your example) `Add` on `a` will really be relayed to the instance of `adder` assigned to `a.Adder`. If `Embed` was to implement `Add` itself, then that method would be called instead (overriding) given the caller is not explicitly bypassing it by calling `a.Adder.Add`.

Comment: Just updated my answer to be more specific about what it means to satisfy versus implement an interface. Fair point thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I correct in assuming my_struct"implements" the Dynamo interface, and now can use the DescribeTableWithContext method?

No. What this does is it embeds an unnamed field of type `Dynamo` in your struct. You will be able to call `DescribeTableWithContext` directly on instances of `my_struct` (such as `var my_struct_instance my_struct`), but this call will actually call the implementation of whatever you assigned to `my_struct_instance.Dynamo`, not the implementation within `my_struct` (because it doesn't define `DescribeTableWithContext`, and thus does not implement `Dynamo`). Doing so may only go well (i.e. not panic) after setting `my_struct_instance.Dynamo` to a value (or pointer to a value) with a type which implements `Dynamo`. Implementation of interfaces in Go is done via [duck typing](https://putridparrot.com/blog/interfaces-and-duck-typing-in-go/).